# system call timing variance

Tags: linux, time, pipe, system-calls

When I measure pipe syscall time 5 times, it shows some significant fluctuation in time (ms). For example, 60ms,62ms and then suddenly 1.40ms and then back 70ms and 63ms. What can be the reason of this kind of time fluctuation?

Comment: How are you measuring the time?

Comment: You're not running a realtime operating system.  You expect to see scheduling variance in pretty much everything, because you don't know what else is getting cpu time while you're waiting.